# How to amend a merge after amended the merged branch?

Tags: git

I'm used to add some little changes (like typo or formatting) to my last commit using `--amend --no-edit`, either in a branch or on master.

However, today I faced for the first time a little problem.
I amended a commit on a branch after having merged that branch with master.

```
                  * branch (X+) (amended)   (this is a chronological view
                  |                          since in fact there is
                  |                           only one commit here)
* master (X) <=>  * branch (X) (merged)
|                 |
|                /
|               /
+--------------/
|
```

So how can I bring that change (the +) on the merged master?

I tried some other merges but that bring some weird merged commits.
Since the original changes (the X) were not complicated I simply hard reset some commits and commit them in one shot.

So how can I bring that change (the +) on the merged master?
*For when I'll have less chance and will be unable to do hard resets*

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mean that you ran `git checkout <branch1>; git merge <branch2>; git commit --amend` and edited the commit message during the `git commit --amend`? Also, it would be helpful if you posted the first few output lines of `git log --decorate --oneline --graph master branch` (with scrubbing of the commit text if you like).

Comment: Hi, here is the exact workflow (considering the branches <master> and <branch>): `git checkout <master>; git merge <branch>`. Then later on I amended the <branch> without changing the message, like so: `git checkout <branch>; git commit --amend --no-edit`. At this time I have same descriptions on the last commits of both branches thus it appears to be the same commits.. In fact it should, but not anymore since the `--amend`. So how I can fix such a situation? Unfortunately, I did not have any trace since I finally went with some resets and reworks (what I'm not supposed to do when using git :(

Answer (score 8):

You said (per comments) that you ran:

> ```
> git checkout master
> git merge branch
> ```

(in that order).  Assuming this works, there are two main possibilities: you got a *fast forward* (which is not actually a merge), or you got a true merge.  I'll assume that you got a true merge, in which Git had to find a merge base commit between the two branch tips.  This arises from a situation in which there are commits "ahead of" the merge base on both branches (the merge base itself is on both branches simultaneously, while the "ahead of" commits are only on one or the other):

```
...--o--o--*--M1--M2   <-- master
            \
             B1--B2--B3   <-- branch
```

Here, instead of Git's raw hash IDs, I've used `Mn` to mark commits that are currently only contained within the `master` branch, and `Bn` to mark commits that are currently only on the branch named `branch`.

By running `git checkout master`, you told Git to make `M2` your *current commit*.  The name `master` identifies this particular commit at this time, and the special name `HEAD` (in all uppercase) is now "attached to" `master`:

```
...--o--o--*--M1--M2   <-- master (HEAD)
            \
             B1--B2--B3   <-- branch
```

Then, `git merge branch` located commit `B3`, which is the commit that the name `branch` identifies at this time.  Git then locates the *merge base* commit on its own.  Here, that's commit `*`, because that's the "nearest" commit that's on, or contained within, *both* `master` and `branch`.  (Note that all the commits before `*` are also on both branches.)

Git compares the merge base `*` to both tip commits, i.e., runs the equivalent of:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-*> <hash-of-M2>   # what happened on master?
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-*> <hash-of-B3>   # what happened on branch?
```

Git then combines these two sets of changes: whatever changed by reaching forward to `M2`, Git applies to `*`; and whatever changed by reaching forward to `B3`, Git *also* applies to `*`.  If, somewhere in these sets-of-changes, there are *overlapping* changes, Git tries to figure out how to combine them correctly.  This may result in a *merge conflict* (if Git can't figure it out), or not (if Git thinks it can).

Often, the merge goes well, and in that case, Git takes the combined results and writes them into both the work-tree (where you can see them) and Git's *index* (which Git uses to make each new commit).  Even if the merge fails, Git still writes everything into the index and work-tree, it just uses an extra feature of the index, and leaves the combined, conflicting files in the work-tree for you to sort out manually.  You do this sorting-out, `git add` the result to resolve the index conflict, and manually run `git commit` instead of having Git do it automatically.  Either way, in the end, you or Git make a new commit from the result.

What's special about the new commit is that it has *two* parents.  The first parent is the *current* commit—in this case, commit `M2`—and the second parent is the other commit, which is `B3` here:

```
...--o--o--*--M1--M2----M3
            \          /
             B1--B2--B3   <-- branch
```

Then Git does the same thing it always does with *any* new commit, merge or no merge: it writes the *new* commit's hash ID into the current branch name, i.e., the one to which `HEAD` is attached.  So now we know what happened to `master` itself, and can draw that in too:

```
...--o--o--*--M1--M2----M3   <-- master (HEAD)
            \          /
             B1--B2--B3   <-- branch
```

Then you did some other work.  For now let's assume this did not change any of these commits, so that the picture above is still valid.  Eventually, you ran:

> ```
> git checkout branch
> ```

which makes the commit to which the name `branch` points become the current commit, and attaches `HEAD` to `branch`:

```
...--o--o--*--M1--M2----M3   <-- master
            \          /
             B1--B2--B3   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

Then you ran the problematic command:

> ```
> git commit --amend --no-edit
> ```

For a normal, no-`--amend` commit, what Git would do here is take whatever is in your index right now, make a new commit from it—let's call that commit `B4`—and give the new commit the current commit (`B3`) as its parent, and then make the name `branch` point to `B4`.  The result would look like this:

```
...--o--o--*--M1--M2----M3   <-- master
            \          /
             B1--B2--B3--B4   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

What `--amend` does, though, is *change* the way Git creates new commit `B4`.  Git still uses whatever is in the index, but instead of making `B4`'s parent be `B3`, it makes `B4`'s parent(s) be whatever `B3`'s parent(s) is/are.  Since `B3` is an ordinary commit with one parent, namely `B2`, Git makes `B4` with `B2` as its parent:

```
...--o--o--*--M1--M2----M3   <-- master
            \          /
             B1--B2--B3
                   \
                    B4
```

—and then, to finish off the commit, Git does the *same thing it always does:* it writes the hash ID of the new commit into the current branch, giving you this:

```
...--o--o--*--M1--M2----M3   <-- master
            \          /
             B1--B2--B3
                   \
                    B4   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

#### This is the problem you found yourself having, but what can you *do* about it?

What to *do* about this is more complicated, and depends on the result you want.

The merge commit you made, `M3`, still exists in your repository.  That merge commit hangs on to commit `B3`.  If you have not *published* this commit—i.e., have not given it to others by running `git push`, or letting them take it from you by them running `git fetch` to your computer—then yous is the *only* repository that has this commit `M3`.  This means you can *discard* `M3`:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

The `git reset` moves the name `master` to point to the commit you specify.  Here, the name `HEAD~1` means *Find the current commit, then find its first-parent, and do that first-parent finding one time.*  The first parent of commit `M3` is commit `M2`, so this makes the name `master` point to commit `M2`:

```
...--o--o--*--M1--M2   <-- master (HEAD)
            \       `---.
             B1--B2--B3--M3
                   \
                    B4   <-- branch
```

There is no longer any *name* by which we can find `M3`.  The effect is as if you'd never made `M3` at all.  Since commit `M3` is also the only way you can find commit `B3`, that has the side effect of pretending `B3` is gone as well.  So we can now draw this as:

```
...--o--o--*--M1--M2   <-- master (HEAD)
            \
             B1--B2--B4   <-- branch
```

and now you are in shape to repeat the merge.

If you don't *want* to repeat the merge, or if you have pushed merge commit `M3` to another Git repository, your options change, but I won't go into any further details here as this is long enough already.